# another left join query

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

i have table LS_CLIENT_TRANS

```
CODE_CLIENT  OTHER_CLIENT
4444         4444
4444         8585
```

and table CLIENT

```
CODE_CLIENT  ADRESS
4444         RR
8585         GG
```

how can i get:

```
  CODE_CLIENT  OTHER_CLIENT  ADRESS
    4444         4444         RR
    4444         8585         GG
```

when i use

```
 SELECT *
   FROM LS_CLIENT_TRANS
   LEFT JOIN CLIENT ON LS_CLIENT_TRANS.CODE_CLIENT = CLIENT.CODE_CLIENT
```

i got:

```
CODE_CLIENT  OTHER_CLIENT  ADRESS
    4444         4444         RR
    4444         8585         RR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM LS_CLIENT_TRANS
LEFT JOIN CLIENT ON LS_CLIENT_TRANS.OTHER_CLIENT = CLIENT.CODE_CLIENT
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` on `ON l.OTHER_CLIENT = c.CODE_CLIENT` like so:

```
SELECT
  l.CODE_CLIENT,
  l.OTHER_CLIENT, 
  c.Adress
FROM LS_CLIENT_TRANS l
LEFT JOIN CLIENT c ON l.OTHER_CLIENT = c.CODE_CLIENT
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25b87/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.CODE_CLIENT, t.OTHER_CLIENT, c.ADDRESS
FROM LS_CLIENT_TRANS t 
JOIN CLIENT c ON t.OTHER_CLIENT = c.CODE_CLIENT
```